# loginctl Блокировка экрана

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, kde

При бездействии(долгом) вылазит приложение перекрывающяя экран с большими буквами `"Для разблокировки экрана переключитесь в виртуальный терминал, войдите в систему и выполните команду: loginctl unlock-sessions. Для возврата в графический режим нажмите..."`. Как от этого избавится, это появилось после обновлений. Использую kde5 и linux mint 18, в kde5 отключены любые блокировки. Также это окно вылазит при выходе из спящего режима, сразуже.

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360489 // ну и вообще: google://loginctl+unlock+session

Comment: Это баг? Хехе, поиск результатов особо не дал. И ваша ссылочка тоже ничего не изменила, просьба не ссылочка а ответ.

Comment: нет, это не баг. см. [этот ответ: It's a fallback for the case that something is seriously broken](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360489#c2). а вот что именно у вас в системе «seriously broken», дистанционно ответить вряд ли возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, в кеде намудрили с настройками. Вообще все это настраивается, надо порыться хорошенько. Да и щяс я с минта пересел на kubuntu.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы ты сообщил, как именно тебе удалось решить проблему. Тогда люди, заходящие сюда из поиска смогут твоим способом воспользоваться. Сейчас же твой ответ абсолютно не информативен. "Надо порыться хорошенько" - это можно понять и без stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему удалось решить для OpenSuSE Leap 15.1, 
Необходимо внести изменения в Параметры системы - Рабочая Среда - Поведение Рабочей среды - Блокировка экрана - Вкладка "Внешний Вид" - путём изменения "Тип Обоев".
В моём случае ошибка воспроизводилась если был выбран "Тип обоев:" - World Map .